# How to update column with increased interval vlaue?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in Postgresql with:

```
id qty
1   10
2   11
3   18
4   17
```

I want to add each row a number starting from 1
meaning I want:

```
id qty
1   11   / 10+1
2   13   /11 +2
3   21   /18 +3 
4   21   /17+4
```

first row gets +1, second row +2 , third row +3 etc...

It should be something like:

```
update Table_a set qty=qty+(increased number starting from 1)  order by id asc;
```

how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If column ID is unique then you can use the following way

```
UPDATE Table_a a
SET qty = qty + b.rn
FROM (
    SELECT id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM Table_a
    ) b
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

---

[`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html)

> assigns unique numbers to each row within the PARTITION given the
>   ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 2):

Using windowed function `ROW_NUMBER` will handle gaps in `id`:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_a(id INT PRIMARY KEY, qty INT);

INSERT INTO Table_a(id, qty)
SELECT 1 ,  10
UNION ALL SELECT 2  , 11
UNION ALL SELECT 3 ,  18
UNION ALL SELECT 4 ,  17;

WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS r
 FROM Table_a
)
UPDATE Table_a AS a
SET qty = a.qty + c.r
FROM cte c
WHERE c.id = a.id;

SELECT *
FROM table_a;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your ID's are continuously , than basically the easiest way to do it and the most efficient one:

```
UPDATE table set qty = qty+id;
```

Comment: They are not. there can be deletion of rows.

Comment: than you should use lad's answer.